# Javascript code review - Make element "toggleable"

Tags: javascript

I wrote a Javascript function that solves a typical problem: Given an HTML element, whenever the user clicks on it another HTML element will be shown, on another click it will be hidden.

As I am not a big Javascript guru and I have just recently started to discover the real power of Javascript, I am sure there is at least a couple of problems with my code.

Any feedback is highly appreciated.

(Note that the I'm using jQuery)

```
/**
 * Makes an HTML element with given with ID "targetId" being toggleable 
 * controlled by the click event of the HTML element with ID "controlId".
 * The "controlFunction" is a function that should return true/false based
 * on a whether the target should be showed or hidden.
 * If there is no controlFunction "!targetElement.is(":visible")" will be used.
 * The controlFunction is applied in the context of the control element (so
 * the "this" is going to be the controlElement.
 * 
 * @param targetId
 * @param controlId
 * @param controlFunction
 * @returns
 */

var makeToggleableOnClick = function (targetId, controlId, controlFunction) {
    var targetElement, controlElement, showHideValue; 

    if (!targetId || !controlId) {
        return;
    }
    targetElement = $('#' + targetId);
    controlElement = $('#' + controlId);

    controlElement.css('cursor','pointer');
    controlElement.click(function() {
        if (controlFunction) {
            showHideValue = controlFunction.apply(controlElement,[]);
        } else {
            showHideValue = !targetElement.is(":visible");
        }

        if (showHideValue) {
            targetElement.slideDown();
        } else {
            targetElement.slideUp();
        }
    });
}

/************/
/* EXAMPLE  */
/************/

<input id="controlElement" type="checkbox"/>
<div id="targetElement">
  Bla-bla.
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  makeToggleableOnClick('targetElement', 'controlElement', function() {
    return this.is(':checked');
  });
</script>
```

Comment: well, you can modify the function to use jquery's toggle.

Comment: It's a typo. http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/196985/232821

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use http://api.jquery.com/toggle/ instead

Comment: Oh well so the problem is that I have started to reinvent the wheel... Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

spelling mistake. toogle is spelt 'toggle'

edit: maybe also make your function name smaller i.e toggle or makeToggle

Comment: Damn, I always make that mistake. Thanks.